# How to skip blocks on forked mainnet using Brownie

Tags: openzeppelin, brownie

When working on a forked mainnet, you can use the `openzeppelin` testnet helper called `advanceBlockTo` to skip `x` amount of blocks (Forces a block to be mined, incrementing the block height).

However, there is only javascript API exists. How about Brownie? Is there any way I can skip blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Brownie provides `chain` object to access blockchain related information. Using chain, one can mine and skip blocks. For example, to mine 100 blocks:

`chain.mine(100)`

To verify, you can use `web3.py`.

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("GANAHCE_URL"))

print("Current block is ", w3.eth.get_block("latest")["number"])
chain.mine(100)
print("Current block is ", w3.eth.get_block("latest")["number"])
```